# Retrofit post data with nested request params

Tags: android, retrofit2

Currently I am working with retrofit. I am aware with post data with custom object and normal and multi form data. But i am stuck because i want to post data to server with nested request parameters.

For e.g,

```
devicetype": "simulator",
"deviceid": "6ea09052e5b1fd10",
"appversion": "0.1",
"apiversion": "0.1",
```

Which i can post as a `RequestBody` string because i want post data with images using multiform data. So i have cleared this concept.

But now i have another custom data.

```
  "sitedetail": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "visitorid": "1"
},
```

So how can i pass this as a request params. Do need to pass a *@Body* which we pass as a custom data or json data normally. I stuck here.

**Update**

```
{
"devicetype": "simulator",
"deviceid": "6ea09052e5b1fd10",
"appversion": "0.1",
"apiversion": "0.1",
"timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
"modeltype": "MI A1",
"deviceos": "9.0",
"userdeviceid": "1",
"visitorid": "1",
"siteid": "1",
"visitordetail": {
    "id": "1",
    "userid": "2",
    "name": "xxx",
    "email": "xxx@xxx.in",
    "mobile": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "dealername": "xxx"
},
"sitedetail": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xxx",
    "visitorid": "1"
},
"selections": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "visitorid": "1",
        "siteid": "1",
        "designno": "xxx",
        "qty": "3",
        "roomtype": "xxx",
        "remarks": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "id": "0",
        "visitorid": "1",
        "siteid": "1",
        "designno": "xxx",
        "qty": "3",
        "roomtype": "xxx",
        "remarks": "xxx"
    }
]}
```

Advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: it all depends on how the server expects it

Comment: It's just expect  multiform data using post method.

Comment: `multipart` you mean? Then send it as a part of that multipartbody

Comment: I can send it but it is nested request. I am not figuring out how to deal with it

Comment: I think you should pass RequestBody for your custom data.

Comment: What is nested request? How do you send it?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  Check my update. Before i was sending as a JSON custom data. So there was not an issue. But now i have to send image too with it. So i have to change my request format. So how can i pass that complex data using _MultiformData_? By _Call<APIResponseSiteDetails> addSiteDetails(@Body JsonObject json);_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST Multipart Form Data using Retrofit 2.0 including image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko How is it duplicate Sir? It's not what i want

Comment: that is exactly what you wrote in your comment.

Comment: How can I pass _selections_, _sitedetail_, _visitordetail_ in Multipartform data? As a json i was able to send custom data. But as a multipart i m confused.

Comment: pass it as single JSONObject. How does your server expect it?

Comment: My server will expect as a key pair value not json object. SO how can i do? That link will be useful ?@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: then send it as parts of a multipart request as shown in the question I linked

Comment: or it expects you to send it as POST or GET parameters?

Comment: It's a POST parameters

Comment: Then send it like any other POST parameter. The problem is you probably will need to URLEncode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue.

If anyone want to upload image to server with extra additional parameters to server. Following are the way.

First create method in your retrofit API request interface.

```
@Multipart
@POST("test/test.post.json")
Call<APIResponseSiteDetails> addImages(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> params);
```

Now you have to call this method in your activity or fragment class where you want to call.

```
 Map<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();

if (imageData != null && imageData.size() > 0) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < imageData.size(); i++) {
                            String key = "images[" + i + "]";
                            File file = new File(imageData.get(i).getImageurl());
                            try {
                                File compressedImages = new ImageZipper(AddDetailsActivity.this).compressToFile(file);
                                params.put("" + key + "\"; filename=\"" + file.getName(), getRequestFile(compressedImages));

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```

above snippet code is only for sending image using *MultiPart*. Now if you want to send additional params with it. Then simply use this.

```
params.put("devicetype", toRequestBody(Constants.DEVICE_TYPE)); // This is String request body.
```

Now if you have another custom request using key pair value and want to send single item then you have to crate this way.

```
public Map<String, RequestBody> getAnotherRequest() {
    Map<String, RequestBody> paStringRequestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();
    paStringRequestBodyMap.put("userid", Functions.toRequestBody("1"));
    paStringRequestBodyMap.put("id", Functions.toRequestBody("1"));
    return paStringRequestBodyMap;
}
```

Now you have to add it in main request body then you have to perform.

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, RequestBody> entry : getAnotherRequest().entrySet()) {
                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        RequestBody value = entry.getValue();
                        params.put("details[" + key + "]", value);
 }
```

Now, if you want to send multiple requests, then you need to perform below code,

```
public Map<String, Map> getContacts() {

    Map<String, Map> paStringRequestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();

    if (showRoomDataList != null && showRoomDataList.size() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < showRoomDataList.size(); i++) {

            Map<String, RequestBody> innnerList = new HashMap<>();
            innnerList.put("id", Functions.toRequestBody("0"));
            innnerList.put("visitorid", Functions.toRequestBody("0"));
            innnerList.put("siteid", Functions.toRequestBody("0"));

            innnerList.put("typeid", Functions.toRequestBody(showRoomDataList.get(i).getTypeid()));
            paStringRequestBodyMap.put(i + "", innnerList);
        }
    }
    return paStringRequestBodyMap;
}
```

Now put it to main request,

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map> entry : getContacts().entrySet()) {

                        String key = entry.getKey();
                        Map value = entry.getValue();

                        Iterator it = value.entrySet().iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();

                            RequestBody requestBody = (RequestBody) pair.getValue();

                            params.put("contacts[" + key + "]" + "[" + pair.getKey() + "]", requestBody);

                            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                        }

                    }
```

For image multipart request body

```
private RequestBody getRequestFile(File file) {

    RequestBody fbody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    return fbody;

}
```

For String value request body

```
  public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
  return body;
}
```

So above are the code to perform with single, multiple post request using key pair value with image(Multipart) data. I hope this will help to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should send the json as a request body. To do so you need to [generate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47707564/5465447) a pojo of the corresponding json. Lets call it, `ReqBody` then,

```
// Add header items if required
@POST("endpoint")
Call<ResBody> getData(@Body ReqBody body);
```

Also, add `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` to your `Retrofit.Builder()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the same problem I had few days ago. You can find the whole topic here to see my example: [Is it possible to POST a package of json objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954204/is-it-possible-to-post-a-package-of-json-objects)

You have to do something like this:

```
public interface API {

  @POST("YOUR_ENDPOINT")
  Call<Post> createPost(@Body PostRequest post);
}
```

And create this class:

```
public class PostRequest {
  final Param1Type param1name;
  final Param2Type param2name; 

  PostRequest(Param1Type param1name, Param2Type param2name) {
    this.param1name= param1name;
    this.param2name= param2name;
  }
}
```

Comment: So can i send data with multipart form data too using this ?

Comment: Thats how I did it few days ago and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please share full snippet? So it will be easy for me

Comment: What do you mean by snippet?

Comment: I have checked your link. My question regarding send images. With Json data we can not send image file too.

Comment: How I understanded your question you want to pass some custom data in JSON format? Did I get something wrong?

Comment: No. I passed it before as i posted json format. Now I want to pass that data using multiform data. So in that we can not pass json format data.

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080241/pass-requestbody-to-another-request-body-using-mapstring-requestbody)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, at first you need create a class for the 1st part of the request. So i would create something like this ->

```
class Article(
    @field:Json(name = "devicetype") var devicetype: String,
    @field:Json(name = "deviceid") var deviceid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "appversion") var appversion: String,
    @field:Json(name = "apiversion") var apiversion: String,
    @field:Json(name = "timezone") var timezone: String,
    @field:Json(name = "modeltype") var modeltype: String,
    @field:Json(name = "deviceos") var deviceos: String,
    @field:Json(name = "userdeviceid") var userdeviceid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "visitorid") var visitorid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "siteid") var siteid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "visitordetail") var visitordetail: List<VisitorDetail>    //Call the visitordetail class over here like this
) : Serializable
```

Then create a class file for "visitordetail", like this ->

```
class VisitorDetail(
    @field:Json(name = "id") var id: String,
    @field:Json(name = "userid") var userid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "name") var name: String,
    @field:Json(name = "email") var email: String,
    @field:Json(name = "mobile") var mobile: String,
    @field:Json(name = "dealername") var dealername: String,
    @field:Json(name = "sitedetail") var sitedetail: List<SiteDetail>    //Call the site details class over here like this
) : Serializable
```

Then similary create a class named "sitedetail"

```
class SiteDetail(
    @field:Json(name = "id") var id: String,
    @field:Json(name = "name") var name: String,
    @field:Json(name = "visitorid") var visitorid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "selections") var selections: List<Selections>    //Call the Selections class over here
): Serializable
```

Similarly again do the same, create a class for "selections" like this ->

```
class Selections(
    @field:Json(name = "id") var id: String,
    @field:Json(name = "visitorid") var visitorid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "siteid") var siteid: String,
    @field:Json(name = "designno") var designno: String,
    @field:Json(name = "qty") var qty: String,
    @field:Json(name = "roomtype") var roomtype: String,
    @field:Json(name = "remarks") var remarks: String
):Serializable
```

I have done this in Kotlin, but you can try it out in java to by converting it. The logic is that, you just have to convert all your responses into pojo classes wherever this is a need for calling a nesting request data. Just pass it one by one and then call the main pojo into your retrofit and rest will be handled by the library. And also you can do this for multi part too.
And if there is any silly mistake like missing of comma or something then my apology for that in advance.

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080241/pass-requestbody-to-another-request-body-using-mapstring-requestbody)?