# Pass requestBody to another request body using Map<String,RequestBody>

Tags: android, retrofit2

My code is for send data to server using Multiform data.

**Code:**

```
    Map<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("devicetype", toRequestBody(Constants.DEVICE_TYPE));
            params.put("deviceid", toRequestBody(Functions.getDeviceId(AddDetailsActivity.this)));
            params.put("appversion", toRequestBody(Constants.APP_VERSION));
            params.put("apiversion", toRequestBody(Constants.API_VERSION));
            params.put("timezone", toRequestBody(Functions.getTimeStamp()));
            params.put("modeltype", toRequestBody(Functions.getDeviceModel()));
            params.put("deviceos", toRequestBody(Build.VERSION.RELEASE));
            params.put("userdeviceid", toRequestBody(MySharedPreferences.getCustomPreference(AddDetailsActivity.this, Constants.SHAREDPREFERENCE_USERDETAILS).getUserdeviceid()));

            if (edit.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                params.put("visitorid", toRequestBody(visitorid));
                params.put("siteid", toRequestBody(siteid));
            } else {
                params.put("visitorid", toRequestBody("0"));
                params.put("siteid", toRequestBody("0"));
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < Constants.images_path.size(); i++) {
                String key = "images[" + i + "]";
                try {
                    File compressedImages = new ImageZipper(AddDetailsActivity.this).compressToFile(new File(Constants.images_path.get(i)));
                    params.put("" + key + "\"; filename=\"" + key + ".png", getRequestFile(compressedImages));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

 public static RequestBody toRequestBody(String value) {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value);
    return body;
}
```

Now i want to add another request body to main request body.. But it is not accepting it.

```
 Map<String, RequestBody> paStringRequestBodyMap = new HashMap<>();

    if (addDetailsActivity.getVisitorSites() != null) {
        paStringRequestBodyMap.put("id", Functions.toRequestBody(addDetailsActivity.getVisitorSites().getSiteid()));
        paStringRequestBodyMap.put("visitorid", Functions.toRequestBody(addDetailsActivity.getVisitorSites().getVisitorid()));
    } else {
        paStringRequestBodyMap.put("visitorid", Functions.toRequestBody("0"));
        paStringRequestBodyMap.put("id", Functions.toRequestBody("0"));
    }
    paStringRequestBodyMap.put("name", Functions.toRequestBody(editTextSitename.getText().toString().trim()));
```

Now I want to add *paStringRequestBodyMap* to main *params* request body. But it is not going well. Not accepting the body request. I tried it with *paStringRequestBodyMap.toString()* but i think that is not a good way.

So advanced help would be appreciated!

Comment: just merge them in one `Map`

Comment: Or you want to put a `paStringRequestBodyMap ` as one of the parameters?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes one of parameters. How can i do that ?

Comment: you can send only a String as a parameter. Check how your server expects you to send it.

Comment: when i try  to send _toRequestBody(paStringRequestBodyMap.toString().trim())_ then it just send **{** as a value.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So how can i send? Can you please elaborate ? Am i right with above comment?

Comment: check with debugger what `paStringRequestBodyMap.toString().trim()` will give you. As I said, first you have to check with your server how does it expect it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So i m right with sending values?

Comment: `check with debugger what paStringRequestBodyMap.toString().trim() will give you.` and then you will be able to check if you are right

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: _RequestBody requestFile;
                    //for (int i = 0; i < jsonSite.size(); i++) {
                    requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), jsonSite.values().toString());
                    params.put("sitedetail[" + jsonSite.get("id").toString() + "]", requestFile);
                    params.put("sitedetail[" + jsonSite.get("visitorid").toString() + "]", requestFile);
                    params.put("sitedetail[" + jsonSite.get("name").toString() + "]", requestFile);_ is this correct format to send value from _paStringRequestBodyMap_?@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199941/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-vladyslav-matviienko).